# Convert list field in R to text field in database

Tags: r, list, text

I'm trying to export a *lines spatial object* , defined in R as a list of elements, to a long text/free text field in a DB.

Each element of the list contains a variable no. of points. For example:

`short[[1]]` could have 3 points:

```
0.11  40.63
0.15  40.78
0.17  40.01
```

`short[[2]]` could have 7 points
`short[[3]]` could have 5 points
.......

Note: each pair of values are geographical coordinates.

So each element of the list would go to a free text field in a database.

how do I go about this?  I guess my issue is about converting a list to some sort of text field, or maybe even better, to a json format that can be read as a geometry directly in the database.

I prefer to use the base package, but if there's a method to convert the whole list to a text like structure, and that requires external packages, that's fine.

Any advice welcome. thanks in advance,             p.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what all you are trying to extract - but possibly this helps? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/180682/merge-a-list-of-spatial-polygon-objects-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Just turn your list items into a matrix with 2 columns then a dataframe :

```
processed = rbindlist(lapply(short, function(x)(data.frame(matrix(x, length(x) / 2)))))
```

Note that rbindlist is from the data.table package:

And then rename the columns as appropriate

```
names(processed) = c("Longitude","Latitude"))
```

Comment: Sorry a bit unfamiliar about the method. x would be the list object short? Would each set of points be a row in the matrix, or multiple matrices? Thnx

Comment: So you will get a list of dataframes, where each dataframe is a set of points. Then you have rbindlist to turn them into one dataframe.